# Google Sheets Sentiment Analysis

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-nl

How can I utilize the Google Cloud Natural Language API to perform sentiment analysis for text in a Google Sheet?

Is there an integration available or is there a proper way to integrate their REST API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to hack something together using Google Apps Script.

You can make a copy of:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VPOckCelGrjMoF8llnpE6IEM-UybwT6wrYb5BxVERIw/edit?usp=sharing

Be sure to go into the script editor (**Tools**⇒**Script Editor...**) and specify your `GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY` via Script Properties (**File**⇒**Project Properties**, **Script Properties**).